# Adding and removing HTML elements between 2 web pages using jQuery.

Tags: php, jquery, css, html

I want to create a scheduling application where users can add artists they want to see at a festival on one page and then view their preferred artist selections on a personal schedule page. Artist information is contained in individual DIVs on the lineup page. When a button is checked I want them to appear inside a select div on another page. What is the best way of going about this using jQuery or even PHP? Can someone show me an example way of doing it? Many thanks!

Comment: Are you using a database ? I'd go for this route, personally

Comment: No, no database just want to show a working prototype really

Comment: Maybe only an HTML form with a php processing page, but nothing will persist, then. You'll be able to pass the artists names via POST between the 2 pages (for example). OR you could go for a single page design, and that would maybe make it easier for you, especially if it's only for prototyping

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right. A database would we the right way of going about it, but I've never worked with databases before. It can't be a single page design unfortunately as there is just too much information to display. Its more of a website then an app. Can I not append a div to another page using jQuery?

Comment: To me the trick is only to pass information between the two pages. Afterwards, managing it or styling it with JS or jQuery is always possible. See my "concept" answer about the "passing data" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic concept answer about passing data from one page to another :

HTML (form.html) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="process.php" method="get">
        <input type="checkbox" name="band1" value="1"> Band 1
        <input type="checkbox" name="band2" value="1"> Band 2
        <input type="checkbox" name="band3" value="1"> Band 3
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP (process.php) :

```
<?php

foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
{
    if($value)
    {
        echo $key . " is scheduled<br>";
    }
}

?>
```

Remarks :

- processing should be more thorough in the PHP file
- you can use POST instead of GET (just replace in form tag and php file), removing the data from the second page url
- if you need the data to persist, build a database (MySQL for example) and store the users and their choices in there